# How to convert HTML data to json, php, mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, json

how to convert HTML data to json, example as below, description content how to convert as json, it is from mysql, php., how to send json responce as plain text, but description comes from the mysql db as it is, but how to send the json responce api to androind.

```
public function actionTestanalysis()
{
//echo $keyword=$_POST['keyword'];
    $query= Yii::app()->db->createCommand("select * from test ORDER BY id DESC")->queryAll();
    $arr = array();
    if(count($query) > 0) {

    foreach($query as $query){
    $arr[] = $query;    
    }
    }

    # JSON-encode the response
    $json_response = json_encode($arr);

    // # Return the response
    echo $json_response;


//exit;
}
```

json responce

```
[
    {
        "id": "99",
        "name": "Max-Gain on or before 25th January 2016 in Max India Limited.",
        "description": "
\r\n\tMax India Limited has announced the Record date for Three way De-Merger as 28th January 2016 (Thursday). <\/div>\r\n
\r\n\t <\/div>\r\n
\r\n\tAnyone want to Gain from the three way De-Merger of Max India Group one should buy the shares of Max India Limited on or before – 25th January 2016 (Cum-Date – Monday Tentavily) otherwise to be on safer side you can buy on or before 22nd January 2016(Friday) and get invested in it.<\/div>\r\n
\r\n\t <\/div>\r\n
\r\n\tIf any investor invests for a period Of 12 – 18 Months , this scrip will be a Multifold - Multi Bagger.<\/div>\r\n
\r\n\t <\/div>\r\n
\r\n\tTo View the full report on Max India Limited authored . <\/div>\r\n
\r\n\t <\/div>\r\n
\r\n\tPlease Click The Below Link<\/div>\r\n
\r\n\t

\r\n\t\thttp:\/\/www.test.com\/index.php\/newsOpportunities\/list\/scroll\/no-pain-all-gain-maximum-benefit-in-max-india-ltd<\/a><\/p>\r\n<\/div>\r\n",
        "image": "",
        "status": "unlock"


    },
```

Comment: It is already JSON,  so what is the question?

Comment: i get the result html data in description field, how to convert plain text

Comment: because you have html in your db. try strip_tags();

Comment: yes html in my db, how do i write strip_tags() in above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have also one error in the cycle in your code.

Try this:

```
if (count($query) > 0) {
    foreach ($query as $queryElement) {
        $el = $queryElement;
        $el['description'] = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', strip_tags($el['description'])));
        $arr[] = $el;
    }
}
```

Comment: strip_tags only removes html tags, how to remove \r\n\t , &nbsp

Comment: how can i remove \r\n\t from description sir?

Answer (score 0):

Try before: echo $json_response set header content type to application/json

```
<?PHP
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $json_response;
```

Comment: He has html in the db

Answer (score 0):

Use `htmlentities()` instead of `strip_tags()`, in order to retain actual content stored in db.

Comment: description is stored as html in db, i tried htmlentities(), it display as it is with html tags, \r\n\t lyk that.

Comment: to replace \r\n use htmlentities(nl2br($urString_go_here))